# Как скачать отрезок из видео на youtube?

Tags: javascript, youtube

Онлайн сервисы не нашел,попробовал сделать так:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QsHowU57nic?rel=0&start=160&end=700" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Задав `start` и `end`,но не знаю как это скачать.

Comment: скачать все, обрезать в редакторе/ffmpeg

Comment: Сама задача в том,чтобы максимально автоматизировать это

Comment: youtube-dl "url" && ffmeg ... -ss .. -to ..

Comment: Я глуп,я понял что это,но куда вставлять?)

Comment: Подскажи пожалуйста)